# AngularJS Ng-style

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-style for a div. I tried all sorts of things and checked about it on Google and Stackoverflow but I can't get it to work. Only `testInsideDiv` text gets displayed. I check if I mised any `'` but I don't see it and I have tried a lot of diffrent things. Anyone sees what the problem is?

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-style="{'width' : {{deviceWidth}}, 'height' : {{deviceHeight}}, 'background-image':{{imagePath}}, 'background-size' : {{deviceWidth}} {{deviceHeight}}, 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'" ng-click="addOnClick($event)">testInsideDiv
                </div>
```

And it looks like this in debuger:

```
 <div ng-style="{'width' : 569px, 'height' : 300px,
 'background-image':'url('http://scada.voco.si/Portals/0/Scadas/2/28/28.jpg')',
 'background-size' : 569px 300px}, 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'"
 ng-click="addOnClick($event)"
 class="disable-user-behavior">testInsideDiv
                 </div>
```

Comment: Try loosing the ' inside the url()

Comment: Allready tryed, I get this:
<div ng-style="{'width' : 569px, 'height' : 300px, 'background-image':'url(http://scada.voco.si/Portals/0/Scadas/2/28/28.jpg)', 'background-size' : 569px 300px}, 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'" ng-click="addOnClick($event)" class="disable-user-behavior">testInsideDiv
                </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main error - **you forgot the closing curly brace of the ng-style object**.

You use camelCase if it's easier for you, and if you're interpolating variables, make sure you quote them. However, you probably don't want interpolation, but binding, so by changing scope variables, the style will also change:

```
<div ng-style="{
    width : deviceWidth, 
    height : deviceHeight, 
    backgroundImage: imagePath, 
    backgroundSize: deviceWidth + ' ' + deviceHeight, 
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
    }" ng-click="addOnClick($event)">testInsideDiv</div>
```

See it in action here:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deviceWidth = '460px';
    $scope.deviceHeight = '276px';
    $scope.imagePath = 'url(http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Super-Mario-no-longer-the-007.jpg)';
  
    // changing scope properties will make the style change
    // because the values are not interpolated
    // as in your original code
    $scope.shrink = function() {
      $scope.deviceWidth = '230px';
      $scope.deviceHeight = '138px';
    }
  })
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-style="{
    width : deviceWidth, 
    height : deviceHeight, 
    backgroundImage: imagePath, 
    backgroundSize: deviceWidth + ' ' + deviceHeight, 
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
    }" ng-click="shrink()">testInsideDiv Click to shrink</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must not use the double braces:

```
<div ng-style="{'width': deviceWidth, 'height': deviceHeight}">...</div>
```

Comment: It's worth note that for `background-size`, they must be concatenated as a normal JS string: `deviceWidth + ' ' + deviceHeight`

Comment: I get this then: <div ng-style="{'width' : 569px, 'height' : 300px, 'background-image':'url(http://scada.voco.si/Portals/0/Scadas/2/28/28.jpg)', 'background-size' : 569px + ' ' + 300px, 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'" ng-click="addOnClick($event)" class="disable-user-behavior">testInsideDiv
                </div>

Comment: @paulroho: I removed double braces and now I don't get values of that variables, but instead there is just name of the variable, when HTML is generated.